# Running Migrations with Django to a Remote Database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-ec2, conda

I am attempting to run migrations from an app server to a remote db server with Django 1.10.5 and Postgresql 9.5. These are separate Ubuntu 16.04 EC2 instances. I only installed Postgresql on the remote db server, not on the app server.

I installed Postgresql globally on the db server with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

I updated the pg_hba_conf file:

```
host      all      all      10.0.59.0/24      trust
```

I set the listening addresses on my postgresql.conf file to:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Django lives in a conda environment on the app server. I pip installed psycopg2==2.6.2 into the conda environment. I did not install psycopg2 on the db server.

Here are my Django DATABASE settings, where 'host' is the ip address of the db server:

```
DATABASES: {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis",
        "NAME": "mysite",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "",
        "HOST": "10.0.59.134",
        "PORT": "5432"
    },
}
```

After running:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 171, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "10.0.59.134" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 81, in handle
    connection.prepare_database()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/base.py", line 24, in prepare_database
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 231, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 204, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 171, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "10.0.59.134" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Both EC2 instances are in the private subnet of a custom VPC. The security group settings for the inbound and outbound rules are set so that any form of traffic is allowed to-and-fro either machine.

This is a test site in the private subnet so there's no password or users (but me) for now.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Er, don't know, because you haven't said what you're doing to get that error. Please show the exact thing you did and the full error message.

Comment: Hi Daniel. My apologies. I've updated the question accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in my `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf` file, I did not remove the '#' in front of the 'listen_addresses' variable under CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION.

The variable needs to be:

```
listen_addreses = '*'
```

Everything's working fine. My Django app is on an Ubuntu 16.04 EC2 instance running migrations to a Postgresql database which is on another Ubuntu 16.04 EC2 instance. Both EC2 instances live in the private subnet.